# JAXB - XML to Java Unmarshal - Not Working

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm fairly new to JAXB, but I've been banging my head against this simple XML to Java conversion for quite a while now, and my guess is I'm missing something pretty elementary here.

XML File (To Unmarshal):

```
<metadata created="2014" xmlns="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#"     xmlns:ext="http://musicbrainz.org/ns/ext#-2.0">
 <artist-list count="4" offset="0">
  <artist id="f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419" type="Group" ext:score="100">
   <name>Linkin Park</name> 
   <sort-name>Linkin Park</sort-name> 
   <country>US</country> 
  </artist>
  <artist id="f59c5520-5f46-4d2c-b2c4-822eabf53419" type="Group" ext:score="100">
   <name>Lincoln Park</name> 
   <sort-name>Linkin Park</sort-name> 
   <country>US</country> 
  </artist>
 </artist-list>
</metadata>
```

Metadata.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="metadata", namespace = "http://musicbrainz.org/ns/mmd-2.0#")
public class Metadata {

@XmlAttribute(name = "created")
private String created;

public String getCreated() {
    return created;
}

public void setCreated(String created) {
    this.created = created;
}

@XmlElementWrapper(name="artist-list") 
@XmlElement(name = "artist")
private List<Artist> artists = new ArrayList<Artist>();

public List<Artist> getArtists() {
    return artists;
}

public void setArtists(List<Artist> artists) {
    this.artists = artists;
}

}
```

Artist.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "artist")
public class Artist {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

When I try reading the XML by creating an object of Metadata, I'm able to retrieve the attribute 'created'. However, the artist list does not get populated.

Kindly let me know if I'm missing something here.

Note:
I'm not facing an 'unexpected element' error here. The code executes without any issues; however, the object for 'artists' is not getting populated, whereas the 'created' attributed seems to be receiving the corresponding XML value.